# Convergence of an iterative process for matrix

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence

$\{X^{(k)}\}$ is a sequence of $N\times M$ matrices given by

$X^{(k+1)} = AX^{(k)}B+C$

where $A,B,C$ are $N\times N$, $M\times M$, $N\times M$ matrices repectively.

How can I analysis the convergence of such a sequence?

Intuitively, $\rho(A) < 1$ , $\rho(B) < 1$ seems a reasonable condition to let the sequence converge, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that $X^{(k+1)}=AX^{(k)}B+C$ is the fixed point iteration to obtain the solution of $X-AXB=C$ (whether or not it exists).

You can write this system using the [$\mathrm{vec}$ operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) (using $\mathrm{vec}(AXB)=B^T\otimes A\mathrm{vec}(X)$) as $Kx=c$, where $K=I-B^T\otimes A$, $x=\mathrm{vec}(X)$, and $c=\mathrm{vec}(C)$. The fixed point iteration above then becomes an iteration for $x$:
$$x^{(k+1)}=(I-K)x^{(k)}+c$$
which converges for any initial approximation iff
$$\rho(I-K)=\rho(B^T\otimes A)<1$$
to the solution of $Kx=c$ (if it has one, e.g., if $K$ is nonsingular).

EDIT: The conditions $\rho(A)<1$ and $\rho(B)<1$ are indeed sufficient conditions for the convergence since the eigenvalues of $B^T\otimes A$ are the products of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ (see, e.g., [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Abstract_properties)).

Comment: Yes it is equivalent, and not exist indeed in my problem. $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, anything wrong in my question about spectral radius?

Comment: No I just wanted to show you how to do it.

Comment: @EDIT This is exactly what I look for. Thanks a lot.